# Early and Late game Runes

Tags: league-of-legends

So I recently started playing Fizz and I've seen some builds from some various sites. The Runes I ended up using now are:

- +6.5 Magic Pen.
- +4.5 Armor Pen.
- +45 Ability Power at level 18
- +15 Ability Power

So I'm just thinking, why use +45 AP at level 18? What I mean is that if I get fed early game I'll be good late as well because of items and everything. So that +45 won't do much ( In my opinion ). If I feed early game, that +45 definitely won't do much ( Again, in my humble opinion ). If I stay with a decent score through the whole game, same logic as before. So, I would like to ask. Isn't it better to put Runes focusing only on early game instead of putting some for early and some for late? Because if you get fed early game with the advantage from the, only, early game Runes you will have a huge advantage late game, which means that you won't need as much that +45 AP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depend agains who you're going and what champion you pick.

**MR runes** are very important to survival in the lane (keep in mind that you want to stay as long as possible in the lane and farming/leveling), and usually you're going against another Magic User (ap). **Glyphs** are the way to go in those runes

**Armor runes** are also important in the lane for survival, the minions may kill you if you keep receiving damage (usually when you go after your opponent and go behind the enemy minions, the minions will turn up on you). These runes also help a little in late game. **Seals** are amazing for those runes.

**Armor Pen. runes** are not so much of use, if you are going as Fizz. They are great if you are Vayne for example. But if you want those (as Vayne for example) go for **Marks** and/or **Quintessence**

**Magic Pen. runes** are great for you, in early, mid and end game. **Marks** are usually enough, but you can get some **Quintessence** too.

**Hybrid Penetration. runes** are excellent on Fizz in the early game, but in the end game, you main damage will be upon the magic damage, since you'll hardly be able to do 3 hits in a row against a target (usually, you'll just jump, pop the ultimate, then scape from the mess, while your team finish the opponents and the opponents try to kill you). In the early game, if you are aggressive, you'll be able to jump in behind the minions, hit once or twice each "dive" then retreat. The main point on the Armor pen is the damage on the minions.

---

It's always worth to test **YOUR** play-style, and pay attention to:

- Do you keep receiving minion damage on your engages?
- Do you wait until 6 to start Harassment? or you go for it since level 1?
- Against who you usually play? (do you go for matches that you know who you are going against or it's a "blind date"?

Based on that, you can pick your runes and also, if you want them to be Flat or Scalable.

- Flat before 6 usually.
- Scalable after 6 usually

---

There isn't a "best-rune-set" nor anything like that. But the set of runes that Valentin Grégoire said in [his answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/177068/12936), is a good way:

> - Flat MR Glyphs (blue) x9
> - Flat Armor Seals (yellow) x9
> - AP or Magic Pen Marks (red) x 9
> - AP or Magic Pen Quints x 3 (or put some movement speed in there).

Comment: I may receive minion damage when I trade with the enemy but that depends on how "deep" I want to go. If I look for more than a simple harass then yeah. I'm the aggressive type of player, but I know how to control and freeze lane. I often try to kill the enemy before 6 but that doesn't always happen so I believe that I leave him with half life before 6 and then I ult and kill him. The thing is that scalable Runes won't give you anything important even at level 6. You have to wait until level 18 so it actually doesn't make a difference if you go for the kill before or after level 6, does it?

Answer (score 1):

I am not a Fizz specialist but I would never play with those runes in mid lane. First of all, you don't need armor penetration.
However, what you really need is Magic Resist runes (glyphs). Either scaling (/lvl) or flat MR runes.
If you go flat, you will have more resist in early game. If you go /lvl, you will have less early, but more in late game. This purely depends on your play style. However, I suggest you to use the flat ones.
Without MR, any decent mid player will destroy you. Same goes for armor, certainly against AD champions.

What I would do:

- Flat MR Glyphs (blue) x9
- Flat Armor Seals (yellow) x9
- AP or Magic Pen Marks (red) x 9
- AP or Magic Pen Quints x 3 (or put some movement speed in there).

As said, I am far from a Fizz specialist, but what I provided something generic that is a good start.

Comment: I see your point there. I mean, for a beginner Fizz player maybe it would be better to run more safe Runes like the ones you said. I guess most players would run those, but I start with Crystalline Flask and 4 pots. The sustain I have in the lane is crazy as well as the mana. I played against an Orianna ( I have to admit she wasn't from the best I've ever seen though.. ) and although that her AA deals too much damage I used most of my pots and I survived the lane long enough to dominate her after a few minutes. So I might not have MR and Armour but with these many pots I can make it through.

Answer (score 0):

It's all dependent on which champions you're playing and how you want to play. If you are going to sit back and farm then the something/lvl runes are great since they are more effective than flat runes at the point in the game where you'll start teamfighting. If you play aggressively early game then you will benefit more from flat runes. For example, I prefer using flat runes on nidalee (with exception to the hp/lvl) because her spears and heal don't really do much early game and it gives me a little boost in my hyper aggressive playstyle. Supports, however, can benefit greatly from offensive whatever/level runes because they aren't (in most cases) going to be building much damage. Also, try using magic pen runes on fizz instead of hybrids since he is all magic damage.

Comment: I use the hybrid ones since the first major item I buy is Lich Bane. So I believe that those Runes go well with it.

Comment: Lich bane does magic damage ;) But I'm not going to tell you that you can't use hybrids. If it's what you prefer then thats more power to you :)

Comment: Lich Bane empowers the next basic attack I think. That's why I said it ^^"

Comment: It sure does! Well sort of. "Unique passive- Spellblade: After using an ability, your next basic attack deals 75% bonus AD ( +50% of your total AP) bonus *magic damage*." Having only the sheen will benefit from the extra armor pen but you'll lose that bonus once you finish your lich bane.

Comment: Lots of people find hybrid marks more useful than magic.  Early game fizz has a lot of mixed damage, not just magic damage.  The hybrid pen marks are a little more useful early game because of dash + auto as opposed to flat magic pen.  Hybrid marks scale into the late game slightly worse but is worth it since it's a lot better early.

Comment: I was thinking of asking a question to get that exact answer xD Thanks.